# How to solve problem when numeric change precision in sql server

Tags: sql

I have two tables in a database. There are also two store procedures that fill the tables. The store procedures take the data to insert into the tables from another database(in linked servers). The issue that I am having is:

whenever new data is inserted, it loses precision.
For example: 'amount' in the source database is 51609.5265
what the sps insert into one table is 51610.72
and in the other table it inserts the correct value.

Another example:
'amount' in the source database is 50739.71
one table has 50740.9
and the other has the correct value

the attributes for the tables that takes the amount are numeric(18,2)
and the attributes in db that provides value to sp are of type money.

Do anyone know why this occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numeric(18,2) means 18 digits, 2 of which are behind the decimal place.

Change all to DECIMAL(20,4) and see if your issue is resolved

NOTE: Make sure to change the datatype of your destination columns

Comment: Being more specific I need that if value from source db is 51609.5265 the sps insert 51609.52, if value from source db is 50739.7123 the sps insert 50739.71 and not 50740.90 I guess you suggested changing to DECIMAL(20,4) because you tought that I need more decimals?

Comment: I was suggesting it to first ensure that the rounding of decimal places wasn't causing an issue. i.e. try to get the data from A to B exactly the same, once that works you can make a change to drop decimal places and test again. Although I'm not sure why you would want to drop any decimal places to begin with. Shouldn't that be done in reports? Dropping data from A to B means that data in B is not accurate.

Comment: I solved one case changing to decimal(20, 4) but I am facing another situation. The script that I am working with has 
3 variables: A (decimal(20, 4)), B(numeric(28, 8)), C (money) and the operation is A = B * C but it loses precision. I also tested 
changing the type of A to numeric(28, 8) and to money but it
 has the same behaviour. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. That is fairly messy. Is there no way that you can standardise them across your system? DataType of (money) has a max of 4 decimal places. and you are multiplying against a numeric value with 8 decimal places. This means that your result could have 12 decimal places, but you are putting them into a decimal DataType with 4 (so potentially losing 8 decimal places). I would advise increasing your target variable (A) to be DECIMAL(28,12) instead of DECIMAL(20,4) to ensure no data is lost.

Comment: An example of this is if you have a numeric(28,8) say:   1.12345678   and then you have a money value of say:   2.1234    if you multiple them out you get =   2.385548126652   (12 decimal places)   which you are inserting into a decimal(20,4) so you will get:   2.3855   When working with huge quantities of values and you are losing 8 decimal places during your calculations, you will inevitably have totals that are not accurate.

Comment: Yes, understand. Although, It still behaves the same. For instance, the value that I expect is 224,886.731652 but what is being stored is 224885.000000000000. those decimals are not being assigned.

Comment: When multiplying are you CASTing/CONVERTing the values? i.e. don't sum money * numeric(28,8)   ,   maybe try    CAST(money AS DECIMAL(20,4)) * CAST(numeric AS DECIMAL(28,8))      replacing "money"/"numeric" with the fieldnames.       also can you confirm that you are unable to change the source table structures?

Comment: It continue the same. Yes I can't change the source table structures.

Comment: I don't think I can help much more without seeing the 2 procedures that are being used, or any views that might be used during the process. If you update your question with some sample data and any script that is used taking the data from 1 server to the other.

Comment: Thank you. It finally worked. The issue was finally fixed by assigning sizes to temporal table attributes. Before inserting the values in the final table they were first saved in temporary tables that had attributes without specifying the range and since that moment, precision was lost.

Comment: No problem, glad you finally got sorted.